visual c++ x64 release mode d3d11 exception access violation
This issue only happens with the visual studio c++ x64 release settings and when I don’t have the flag D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG activated (which would be really useful to see warnings and traceability). On the other hand, if I enable that flag this problem will never happen, so I am stuck and unable to figure out what could cause the crash since I don’t have much information to work with. Not to mention that it is not acceptable to have this flag activated as solution.
exception call stack
Any idea on how to investigate further in this specific issue?
Thanks
I have tried to reproduce the problem using different settings such as debug/release with x64/x86 platforms and it only happened to me with the x64 release settings. Even with the x64 debug and the flag D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG inactive I wasn't able to get the reported error.

Don't post images of code, post code Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? as for your problem, it's impossible to help just looking at your description in english and/or a stackframe that sits in D3D11, we're not psychics. Please post some real reproducing code How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#configure-location-of-symbol-files-and-loading-options

First, with the DEBUG layer enabled, look to see if you are getting any ERROR or WARNING messages from the system. Second, enable use of the Microsoft Symbol Server so you can actually see anything useful in the callstack.
One of the most common reasons for a Release failure that doesn't show up in Debug is an uninitialized variable, so check that.
